# Selenium java issue

Tags: java, selenium

I was unable to figure out an issue.

The method testTest1() was not executing. It should open yahoo.com.

```
package example1;

import org.testng.annotations.*;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class SimpleTest extends SeleneseTestCase {

    private DefaultSelenium selenium;


    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)

    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        echo("in setup.");

        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 

                4444, "*opera", "http://localhost:8080/");

        echo("selenium instance created:"+selenium.getClass());

        selenium.start();

        echo("selenium instance started. Opening website...");

    }


    @Test(sequential=true)

    public void testTest1() throws Exception {

        echo("testTest1:testing assertion.");

        selenium.open("http://www.yahoo.com");

    }



    // Cleanup the selenium environment

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)    

    private void stopTest() {

        selenium.stop();

        echo("selenium stopped.");

    }


    private void echo(String msg){
 System.out.println(msg);

        if(new Boolean(System.getProperties().getProperty("DEBUG")))

            System.out.println(msg);

    }



    }
```

The script was not opening yahoo.com 
and it says finally:

```
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Can any one tell me what's needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with selenium but is a problem with how you are running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Hi jzd 
I am following like this
**for starting server** 
srinath@srinath-Vostro1510:~/Desktop/testws/lib$ java -jar selenium-server.jar -multiwindow
20:17:34 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
20:17:34 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
20:17:34 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
20:17:34 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
20:17:34 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
20:17:34 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@3487a5cc

**now running command to start scripts** :

srinath@srinath-Vostro1510:~/Desktop/testws$ ant run
Buildfile: /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/build.xml

setClassPath:

init:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/build

compile:
     [echo] making directory...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/build
     [echo] classpath: /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/junit.jar:/home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/selenium-java-client-driver-tests.jar:/home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/selenium-java-client-driver.jar:/home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/selenium-server-0.9.1-20070223.200626-116-standalone.jar:/home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/selenium-server.jar:/home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/testng-5.5-jdk15.jar:/home/srinath/Desktop/testws/lib/testng.jar
     [echo] compiling...
    [javac] /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/build.xml:68: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/build

run:
   [testng] [Parser] Running:
   [testng]   /home/srinath/Desktop/testws/config/testng.xml
   [testng] 
   [testng] in setup.
   [testng] selenium instance created:class com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium
   [testng] selenium instance started. Opening website...
   [testng] 
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] suite1
   [testng] Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 59 seconds

Comment: Got solved . need to configure in xml file where we call the methods to execute .